# Android: Cursor Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a program where you click a button, and a dialog pops up with a bunch of checkboxes.  You choose a few of the checkboxes, and then click "ok".  What I am trying to do is have it so that when you press ok, for each value you checked off, it will search several database tables for rows containing that value, take information from those rows, and put them in a different table.  For some reason I keep getting this cursor out of bounds exception and I honestly cannot figure out why.  I tried a bunch of things that I found while searching and I cannot get it to work.

Here is what happens when you click ok:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (dumbbells.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "dumbbells";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (barbell.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Barbell";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (cablemachine.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Cable Machine";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (pullupbar.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Pull Up Bar";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (legpressmachine.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Leg Press Machine";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (legextensionmachine.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Leg Extension Machine";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (hamstringcurlmachine.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Hamstring Curl Machine";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (kettlebells.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "Kettlebells";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }
        if (none.isChecked()==true){
            equip = "None";
            AddToEquipTable(equip);
        }


    }
});
```

Here is the "AddToEquipTable" method I created:

```
public void AddToEquipTable(String equip){

ExerciseDatabase equipment = new ExerciseDatabase(WorkMeOutActivity.this);
try {
    equipment.open();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromBiceps(equip);
equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromChest(equip);
equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromBack(equip);
equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromTriceps(equip);
equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromShoulders(equip);
equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromLegs(equip);
equipment.AddToEquipmentDBFromCompound(equip);

equipment.close();
}
```

And here is one of the methods it calls in my DB Helper Activity.  They are all the same, except for the table name called.

```
public String AddToEquipmentDBFromBiceps(String equip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REPS, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_TIMETYPE};
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE, columns, KEY_EQUIP + "='" + equip + "'", null, null, null, null);

    if (c == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(c != null){

        c.moveToFirst();

        int iReps = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPS);
        int iExercise = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);
        int iTimeType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMETYPE);



        do{

            String reps = c.getString(iReps);
            String exercise = c.getString(iExercise);
            String time = c.getString(iTimeType);

            cv.put(KEY_REPS, reps);
            cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE, exercise); 
            cv.put(KEY_TIMETYPE, time);

            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_CHOSEN_EQUIP_TABLE, null, cv);

            c.moveToNext();

            }while(KEY_EQUIP == equip);
        }


    return null;
}
```

**Error Log After Changing Condition as Suggested Below:

```
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.work.me.out.ExerciseDatabase.AddToEquipmentDBFromLegs(ExerciseDatabase.java:896)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.work.me.out.WorkMeOutActivity.AddToEquipTable(WorkMeOutActivity.java:456)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.work.me.out.WorkMeOutActivity$9.onClick(WorkMeOutActivity.java:395)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-24 09:34:42.785: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have bad condition, change yours with:

```
while (c.moveToNext() && KEY_EQUIP == equip);
```

**Note:** Also i recommend to you use `parametrized statements` which are more safe, faster and clearer.

---

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

It means that `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false and `Cursor` is empty.
So try to add this snippet and try it.

```
else if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        int iReps = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPS);
        int iExercise = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);
        int iTimeType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMETYPE);
        do {
            String reps = c.getString(iReps);
            String exercise = c.getString(iExercise);
            String time = c.getString(iTimeType);

            cv.put(KEY_REPS, reps);
            cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE, exercise); 
            cv.put(KEY_TIMETYPE, time);

            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_CHOSEN_EQUIP_TABLE, null, cv);
            } while (c.moveToNext() && KEY_EQUIP == equip);
        }
```

Try to use `rawQuery` method similar like this:

```
final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT " + KEY_REPS + ", " + KEY_EXERCISE + ", " + KEY_TIMETYPE + " FROM " + DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_EQUIP + " = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, new String[] {equip});
```

Comment: I just tried that...still getting the same cursor out of bounds exception

Comment: see me updated answer and replace your fragment of condition with mine.

Comment: that does not produce any error, but it also does not put any values into the chosen_equip_table.

Comment: because your condition never be process because your cursor is empty, you need to check your cursor wether is right or not.

Comment: When I had it the way I did originally, if I chose the first checkbox, it worked fine, because all of the tables contained something with the value from the first checkbox.  But once chose any other checkbox, it would crash and give me the cursor out of bounds exception.  Do you think I need to check if the value exists in the table first?

Comment: Calling c.moveToFirst() followed by c.moveToNext() on the next line means your skipping the first row of data in the cursor. Have a look at my answer

Comment: now it will works i think, first you must check if moveToFirst returns true, if returns, cursor cotains data, if not cursor is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you are pointing at the first row of the cursor before you try and access any data, specifically the lines `c.getColumnIndex(KEY_XXX)`. You've called `c.moveToFirst()` without checking its result (which in your case should return false as there are no rows of data.

```
if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    int iReps = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPS);
    int iExercise = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);
    int iTimeType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMETYPE);

    do {
        String reps = c.getString(iReps);
        String exercise = c.getString(iExercise);
        String time = c.getString(iTimeType);

        cv.put(KEY_REPS, reps);
        cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE, exercise); 
        cv.put(KEY_TIMETYPE, time);

        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_CHOSEN_EQUIP_TABLE, null, cv);    
    } while(c.moveToNext() && KEY_EQUIP == equip);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Note that its important to use a `do..while` loop here instead of a regular `while` loop, as calling `c.moveToFirst()` followed by `c.moveToNext()` straight after it means you are missing the first row of cursor data!